# How to enable CORS on a blazor webassembly, hosted by a razor pages app with controller API services

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly, c#-6.0

I have a blazor web assembly project with various razor pages components, each embedded in the different razor pages of a razor pages web application and utilising a blazor HttpClient to communicate with the MVC API controllers in the razor pages app.
The HttpClient returns a CORS error in the console when connecting to the API.
I've added the following code at the appropriate places in the start file:

```
string? origins = "origins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
     options.AddPolicy(origins,
                           policy =>
                           {
                                policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9999")
                                                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                   .AllowAnyMethod();
                           });
});

app.UseCors(origins);
```

But this still shows up in the browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

What to do, please?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to apply that CORS on the **app that hosted** your Blazor WASM, and not on the blazor wasm project. Make sure you put builder.Services.AddCors(...) before the builder.Build().

You can read further this documentation on various way to enable cors.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attr

Comment: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddCors' and no accessible extension method 'AddCors' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)